# How do I access an array value inside a case in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm new to Splunk and need some help with the following:

- authIndexValue[] is an array that will hold at least one value
- I want to access its value from inside a case in an eval statement but I get
  this error: Unknown search command '0'.
- I also tried http.request.queryParameters.authIndexValue{} with no luck

Below the eval line:

```
..search
| eval EventType=case(http.request.queryParameters.authIndexValue[0]==Login_FooBar, "LOGIN")
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splunk doesn't have "arrays"

It has [multivalue fields](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Search/Parsemultivaluefields)

To access/do anything with them, you need to use multivalue commands/functions

- multivalue eval functions - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions
- multivalue stats functions - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Multivaluefunctions

In your example, you'd want to do something *like* the following:

```
<search>
| eval EventType=case(mvindex(http.request.queryParameters.authIndexValue,0)==Login_FooBar,"LOGIN", mvindex(http.request.queryParameters.authIndexValue,0)==Login_BarFoo,"not a good login",1=1,"error state")
```

Comment: Not working apparently, I also tried to get the values count with: 

 - | eval indexv=mvcount(http.request.queryParameters.authIndexValue) 

it didn't return anything. authIndexValue is comming in as an array [] in JSON format. Is that considered multivalue according to SPLUNK?

Comment: @RaulMarquez - what is the actual field name? I suspect, if it's JSON, it might actually be `http.request.queryParameters{}.authIndexValue`, perhaps?